# storing record arrays in object arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to convert a list of record arrays -- dtype is (uint32, float32) -- into a numpy array of dtype `np.object`:

```
X = np.array(instances, dtype = np.object)
```

where `instances` is a list of arrays with data type `np.dtype([('f0', '<u4'), ('f1', '<f4')])`. 
However, the above statement results in an array whose elements are also of type `np.object`:

```
X[0]
array([(67111L, 1.0), (104242L, 1.0)], dtype=object)
```

Does anybody know why?

The following statement should be equivalent to the above but gives the desired result:

```
X = np.empty((len(instances),), dtype = np.object)
X[:] = instances
X[0]
array([(67111L, 1.0), (104242L, 1.0), dtype=[('f0', '<u4'), ('f1', '<f4')])
```

thanks & best regards, 
 peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stéfan van der Walt (a numpy developer) [explains](http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/Structured-array-inititialization-weirdness-td23335.html#a23337):

> The ndarray constructor does its best
>   to guess what kind of data you are
>   feeding it, but sometimes it needs a
>   bit of help....
>
> I prefer to construct arrays
>   explicitly, so there is no doubt what
>   is happening under the hood:

When you say something like

```
instance1=np.array([(67111L,1.0),(104242L,1.0)],dtype=np.dtype([('f0', '<u4'), ('f1', '<f4')]))
instance2=np.array([(67112L,2.0),(104243L,2.0)],dtype=np.dtype([('f0', '<u4'), ('f1', '<f4')]))
instances=[instance1,instance2]
Y=np.array(instances, dtype = np.object)
```

`np.array` is forced to guess what is the dimension of the array you desire. 
`instances` is a list of two objects, each of length 2. So, quite reasonably, `np.array` guesses that `Y` should have shape (2,2):

```
print(Y.shape)
# (2, 2)
```

In most cases, I think that is what would be desired. However,
in your case, since this is not what you desire, you must construct the array explicitly:

```
X=np.empty((len(instances),), dtype = np.object)
print(X.shape)
# (2,)
```

Now there is no question about X's shape: `(2, )` and so when you feed in the data

```
X[:] = instances
```

numpy is smart enough to regard `instances` as a sequence of two objects.