# Numpy object arrays

Tags: python, arrays, class, numpy

I've recently run into issues when creating Numpy object arrays using e.g.

```
a = np.array([c], dtype=np.object)
```

where c is an instance of some complicated class, and in some cases Numpy tries to access some methods of that class. However, doing:

```
a = np.empty((1,), dtype=np.object)
a[0] = c
```

solves the issue. I'm curious as to what the difference is between these two internally. Why in the first case might Numpy try and access some attributes or methods of `c`?

EDIT: For the record, here is example code that demonstrates the issue:

```
import numpy as np

class Thing(object):

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print "in getitem"

    def __len__(self):
        return 1

a = np.array([Thing()], dtype='object')
```

This prints out `getitem` twice. Basically if `__len__` is present in the class, then this is when one can run into unexpected behavior.

Comment: Not related, but why `np.object` and not just `object`?

Comment: The two are equivalent (``object == np.object`` returns ``True``) so this is not related to the issues I'm seeing.

Comment: @astrofog That's why I asked and said it wasn't related.

Comment: BTW, I don't think one can solve your problem without seeing the class and some error messages.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641701/storing-record-arrays-in-object-arrays)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the first case `a = np.array([c], dtype=np.object)`, numpy knows nothing about the shape of the intended array.

For example, when you define

```
d = range(10)
a = np.array([d])
```

Then you expect numpy to determine the shape based on the length of `d`.

So similarly in your case, numpy will attempt to see if `len(c)` is defined, and if it is, to access the elements of `c` via `c[i]`.

You can see the effect by defining a class such as

```
class X(object):
    def __len__(self): return 10
    def __getitem__(self, i): return "x" * i
```

Then

```
print numpy.array([X()], dtype=object)
```

produces

```
[[ x xx xxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx]]
```

In contrast, in your second case

```
a = np.empty((1,), dtype=np.object)
a[0] = c
```

Then the shape of `a` has already been determined.  Thus numpy can just directly assign the object.

However to an extent this is true only since `a` is a vector.  If it had been defined with a different shape then method accesses will still occur. The following for example will still call `___getitem__` on a class

```
a = numpy.empty((1, 10), dtype=object)
a[0] = X()
print a
```

returns

```
[[ x xx xxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx]]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed - basically if ``__len__`` is defined then that is when I run into issues!